# ERROR 1227 (42000) at line 18: Access denied, MYSQL 8 import table

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, mysql-8.0

when I am trying to import tables in mysql8 I am getting below error.

```
ERROR 1227 (42000) at line 18: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER, SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN or SESSION_VARIABLES_ADMIN privilege(s) for this operation
```

I am using rds. I already created a new parameter group and set

> log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1

value as per answer in some other question but still not working.

Comment: is the created parameter group attached with RDS?

Comment: yes I have attached